# Manage Subject Alternative Name for App Service Certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice, subject-alternative-name

I purchased an app service certificate and would like to manage hostname in Subject Alternative Name(SAN) but unsure how it can be edited. Goal is to secure sub-domain using same cert without purchasing new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently managing\editing SAN for App Service Cert is not a supported feature yet. However, our product group is working on this requirement.

In meantime, as a workaround for your current issue our new free App Service Managed Certificate feature will help you to secure your sub-domain with a new certificate at no cost.

More details about this feature can be read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#create-a-free-certificate-preview).

**Note**: This feature has it’s own limitations, However it should help unblock your current issue.